# How to change the background color of specific JTable cells depending on their value?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablemodel

How can I color the background of the cells in the first column to red if their value equals Kathy or Jane.

In my solution, every cell in the first column painted to red, but everything works fine, if I colour the other cells to green. But I want to let their background on default, because I just want to mark specific cells.

```
package com.myswingtest;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name","Last Name"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Black",},
            {"John", "Doe",},
            {"Jane", "Smith",},
            {"Rob", "White",},
            {"Joe", "Smith",}
        };

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        DefaultTableCellRenderer statusCellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {      
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
                int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();
                // Lets color only the cells in the first column what equals Kathy or Jane
                if("Kathy".equals(tableModel.getValueAt(modelRow, 0)) 
                        || "Jane".equals(tableModel.getValueAt(modelRow, 0))){
                    System.out.println("SETTING COLOR TO RED IN ROW: " + modelRow);
                    l.setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    // If I uncomment this line, the other lines became green. But I want their background stay default.
                    //l.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }
                return l;
            }
        };
        // Setting cellrenderer for first column
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(statusCellRenderer);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new SimpleTableDemo());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I rewrited the question and included the suggested SSCE.

Comment: `else{ l.setBackground(table.getBackground()); }`

Comment: it works, by why does swing do this?